# Python3 + PyGobject + GTK3 and cx_freeze missing DLLs

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, cx-freeze, pygobject

When I make a exe from py python3 + pygobject + gtk3 application using the [setup.py](https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=setup.py) from pygobject site it misses some DLL files.

what files are missing?

Comment: I think the new GObject introspection system loads the libraries dynamically, so cx_Freeze at present can't follow the links to work out what libraries it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manualy tried what DLLs are required. So if this will help someone:

the [setup.py](https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=setup.py) must be edited. the **missing_dlls** list must be:

```
missing_dll = ['libgtk-3-0.dll',
           'libgdk-3-0.dll',
           'libatk-1.0-0.dll',
           'libcairo-2.dll',
           'libcairo-gobject-2.dll',
           'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
           'libjpeg-8.dll',
           'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
           'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
           'libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll',
           'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
           'libgirepository-1.0-1.dll',
           'libffi-6.dll',
           'libfontconfig-1.dll',
           'libfreetype-6.dll',
           'libgio-2.0-0.dll',
           'libglib-2.0-0.dll',
           'libgmodule-2.0-0.dll',
           'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
           'libpng15-15.dll',
           'libpyglib-gi-2.0-python-0.dll',
           'libxml2-2.dll',
           'zlib1.dll',
           'libgnutls-26.dll',
           'librsvg-2-2.dll',
           'libgcrypt-11.dll',
           'libp11-kit-0.dll']
```

and when you dont want all the files from `share`, `etc` and `lib`, edit the **gtk_libs** list:

```
gtk_libs = ['lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0',
            'lib/girepository-1.0',
            'share/glib-2.0',
            'share/gtk-3.0']
```

you might include also the `lib/engines`, but I dont needed it.